# How can I read a Kafka topic with an evolving Avro schema using DLT?

Tags: apache-kafka, databricks, avro, confluent-schema-registry, delta-live-tables

I want to read a Kafka topic (with Avro schema that can evolve) in Databricks using DLT. Is there a way to get the latest version of this schema in a DLT pipeline? There is a way to do it with Structured Streaming using foreachbatch, but I would like to know if I can do it with DLT.

It is possible with Structured Streaming like this article:
https://www.confluent.io/blog/consume-avro-data-from-kafka-topics-and-secured-schema-registry-with-databricks-confluent-cloud-on-azure/#step-8

I would like to achieve the same using DLT, but I don't know if it's possible.